# how to integrate normal distribution with numpy and scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

trying to integrate a normal distribution

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
```

this does not work, throws a type error:

```py
def f_np(x):
  return np.random.normal(size=x)

integrate.quad(f_manual, -np.inf, np.inf)

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.normal()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.cont()

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

but it works if I manually enter the pdf:

```py
def f_manual(x):
   return 1/(1 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-(x - 0)**2 / (2 * 1**2) )

integrate.quad(f_manual, -np.inf, np.inf)

(0.9999999999999997, 1.017819145094224e-08)
```

any idea why?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? The `size` parameter for `np.random.normal` is for the output shape... but you seem to be trying to use it as the argument `x` of the pdf.

Comment: `np.random.normal` is an RNG that follows the normal distribution, it's not the pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things going on here.

`np.random.normal` draws samples from the normal distribution.  The size parameter specifies the number of samples you want.  If you specify 10 you'll get an array with 10 samples.  If you specify a tuple, like `(4, 5)` you'll get a 4x5 array.  Also, `np.inf` is a float and `np.random.normal` is expecting an integer or a tuple of integers for the size parameter.

What you have in `f_manual` is a deterministic function (i.e. the PDF) which returns the value of the PDF at the value `x`.

These are two different things.

`scipy` has a function to return the PDF of a Gaussian: `scipy.stats.norm.pdf`

```py
import scipy.stats
scipy.integrate.quad(scipy.stats.norm.pdf, -np.inf, np.inf)
# (0.9999999999999998, 1.0178191320905743e-08)
```

`scipy` also has a CDF function that returns the integral from -inf to x:

```py
scipy.stats.norm.cdf(np.inf)
# 1.0

scipy.stats.norm.cdf(0)
# 0.5
```